# How to detect the 2nd link on a page using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

The first one below works, that is `a:first` detects the 1st link, but `a:second` doesn't. How can I detect the 2nd link on a page using jQuery?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('a:first').click(function() {
            alert('you clicked 1st link');
        });

        $('a:second').click(function() {
            alert('you clicked 2nd link');
        });

    });
</script>

<a href="#">1st Link</a>
<a href="#">2nd Link</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), like so:

```
$('a').eq(1).click(...);
```

Or the [selector version](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

```
$('a:eq(1)').click(...);
```

It is `1` because `eq` is 0-based.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:eq(1)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) like this:

```
$('a:eq(1)').click(function() {
  alert('you clicked 2nd link');
});
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5Zj2d/). Or [`.eq(1)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) like this:

```
$('a').eq(1).click(function() {
  alert('you clicked 2nd link');
});
```

[Test that version here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5Zj2d/1/). Unlike [`:nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), the eq versions are for the index, which is 0-based.